# Jquery text input acting funny

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following jQuery to modify a table cell when clicked -- it will enable a user to fill out a text input and on enter, return to the normal `<td>`.

HTML-

```
<td class="delivered">
    {{ title.delivery_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}
</td>
```

JS -

```
$("td.delivered").click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('#inp').length == 0) {
        var before = $(this).text();
        var title_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var status_type = 'delivery-date'
        $(this).html($("<input/>", {
            id: 'inp',
            style: 'width:70px;',
            placeholder: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            change: function () {
                selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
            }
        }));
        $("#inp").focus();
        $('#inp').val(before);
    }
});
```

The above js works, but there is a quirk about it.

Even though the input element is 70px, it seems to scroll as if the text width were 200px or so. This makes it so that you are unable to see the `placeholder` after first clicking the td. How would I make it such that that the cursor is **always** flush left and the text input is 70px in every which way.

**Update:** This is what the input looks like after entering text and sending it via `POST`: `u'status': [u'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2012-01-01']`. In other words, it seems to be starting with 11 tabs in the text input! Why does this occur and how would I get rid of this?

Comment: Another function that it is calling, but it shouldn't affect the above js.

Comment: And do you have several of these on the same page? Giving multiple elements the id of `inp` is an issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that is correct, I'll change it to a class.

Comment: You immediately are filling the input with text, so why would you expect the placeholder to show at all?

Comment: The tabs are in the HTML, which you are grabbing with `$(this).text()`. To get rid of them you need to put the opening and closing td tags all in the same line with their content: `<td class="delivered">{{ title.delivery_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your input box in a div with `width:70px;overflow:hidden` so you're sure that you won't see any scrollbars.

Comment: Your data from `$(this).text()` should be cleaned with something like `var before = $(this).text().replace(/\t/g, '');`. Look also at your html file if you don't have unused spaces in your input tag value.